# Being Prompted With "python was not found" Even After Successfully Installing Python 3.8.0 From 'https://www.python.org/downloads/' (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows

I am beginning to learn python, but i'm bumping into a quite irritating issue. I have installed python 3.8.0 from their website. I can still write and run programs in python (using pycharm, for example) but when i enter "python" in Powershell, or cmd.exe, they either give me a warning saying that python could not be found and/or take me to the windows store page for Python 3.7.0.

With this problem happening I'm really not sure if there was some issue during the installation of Python, or if its just related to the path my computer is taking to Python. But it is driving me crazy!

Comment: As an aside, are you not using virtual environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be under different executable name. Have you tried `python3.8` in cmd.exe? Quite often symlink `python` -> `python3.8` is not made, but `python3.8` and `python3` should work.

If not, python installation might not be in your system's `PATH`. [Here](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) are instructions how to view/edit window's environmental variables, including `PATH`. You'll have to locate where python is installed and verify that directory is in PATH or add it.

Comment: Fixed! it was a PATH related issue. Thank you :)